# ERROR: Preparation failed: Getwd: getwd: no such file or directory

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

Gitlab runner throw ERROR: Preparation failed: Getwd: getwd: no such file or directory?

gitlab version is: GitLab Community Edition 8.6.4
gitlab-runner version:  1.11.5

My CI throw `ERROR: Preparation failed: Getwd: getwd` frequently,
but sometimes we commit is work fine. So we didn't know what the final reason cause this problem.

We only know about one thing that is this error shows after we moved the build directory.

Comment: Please put content of /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/gitlab-runner.service here

Comment: I was having the same issue for a while but out of nowhere without any directory change. Removing the gitlab-runner from the installed machine, rebooting it and reinstalling it solved the issue for me. In your case based on [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/154) it might be enough to uninstall service - restart - reinstall service with the new directory.

Comment: I also had to uninstalled and reinstalled after some messing around with the build dir. I used the following command to uninstall:
sudo gitlab-runner uninstall
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner
sudo userdel gitlab-runner
sudo rm -rf /home/gitlab-runner/

Answer (score 5):

In my case that was because of residual gitlab-runner processes still executing. I resolved it by identifying guilty pids then killed them:

```sh
$ ps -ax | grep gitlab-runner
27034 ?        Ssl    0:06 /usr/bin/gitlab-runner run --working-directory /home/gitlab-runner --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --syslog --user gitlab-runner
$ sudo kill -9 27034
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error and solved by restarting `gitlab-runner`

```
gitlab-runner restart
```

Comment: It happen for me frequency :(

Answer (score 0):

The Gitlab Runner checks out a copy of your repository into `CI_PROJECT_DIR`. You can check its value by adding the following to your `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
script:
  - echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR
```

I received the "getwd: no such file or directory" error because:

- I had changed my working directory to `/var/www/mysite` (I am using a docker container with gitlab-runner installed inside it, but I think that's beside the point)
- one of my deploy script lines moves `/var/www/mysite` to `/var/www/old-mysite`.

I'm used to the Gitlab Runner checking out its build inside `/home/gitlab-runner/build`. When I changed the docker working directory this caused the runner to check it out at `/var/www/mysite/build`.

After my script moved `/var/www/mysite` to `/var/www/old-mysite`, on second and subsequent runs, gitlab runner still expected to find (`/var/www/mysite`) but it no longer existed, hence the error.

Given the above, I can't explain why the runner works the first time ever, when that directory also doesn't exist, but hopefully my answer might at least prompt something useful for someone! :)